# Android Facebook SDK 3.2 Revoke Api Access

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I want to revoke api access of a user if user does not give email permission. I'm using Facebook SDK 3.2.1. All documents i found about revoke api access are for latest Facebook Android SDK

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working solution:

```
new Request(
                 FacebookSession,
                 "/me/permissions",
                 null,
                 com.facebook.HttpMethod.DELETE,
                 new Request.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(com.facebook.Response response) {
                       // Revoked access
                    }
                 }
         ).executeAsync();
```

if you want to revote spesific permissions put it at the end of:

```
"/me/permissions/permissions-to-revoke"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the http call yourself if you want to. After all, this is what's happening under the hood:

```
DELETE /{user-id}/permissions/
```

This will uninstall the app if no specific permission is specified. [reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/permissions#Overview)